# How to use a delegate between a Winforms Form and a WPF Usercontrol hosted by an elementhost in the Winforms form?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, delegates, elementhost

I have a Winforms app (class named Form_WinForms for the example) and I want to add an elementhost control to it in order to host a WPF Usercontrol (named Form_WPF).

But I don't know how to handle the delegates between them: I want to exchange with the Form_WPF controls from the Form_WinForms and vice versa. How could I do ? Thanks

In the example, I just want to modify the text of the control textbox (WPF technologie) by clicking inside a Winforms button.

In Winforms class:

```
// In Form_WinForms (my main form)

private void btn_Debug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Form_WPF.GetInstance().Invoke(new ChangeTextBox_WPF(Form_WPF._ChangeTextBox_WPF), Form_WPF.GetInstance().TextBoxDebug, "test"); // what I would have done if Form_WPF was a WinForms form 
    Form_WPF.GetInstance().Dispatcher.Invoke(new ChangeTextBox_WPF(Form_WPF._ChangeTextBox_WPF), Form_WPF.GetInstance().TextBoxDebug, "test");
}
```

In WPF class:

```
// In the Usercontrol Form_WPF (which is hosted by an elementhost in Winforms)

private delegate void ChangeTextBox_WPF(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox TextBox, String texte);
public static void _ChangeTextBox_WPF(System.Windows.Controls.TextBox TextBox, String texte) { TextBox.Text = texte; TextBox.Tag = texte; }

private static Form_WPF _Form_WPF;

public static Form_WPF GetInstance()
{
    if (_Form_WPF == null)
    {
        _Form_WPF = new Form_WPF();
    }
    return _Form_WPF;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast the `Child` property of the `ElementHost` to your WPF control type, e.g.:

```
Form_WPF wpfControl = elementHost.Host as Form_WPF;
```

Then you can access any members of the hosted instance as usual.

Comment: Hi, the `child` property of my elementhost was already to Form_WPF, the delegate function `_ChangeTextBox_WPF` is triggering when I press the Winforms debug button, but the text of the WPF textbox is not changing

Comment: Probably because you set the `Text` property of the wrong instance. Remove all static stuff. You don't need it.

Comment: If I remove it I have the followings error on the line  `Form_WPF.GetInstance().Dispatcher.Invoke(new ChangeTextBox_WPF(Form_WPF._ChangeTextBox_WPF), Form_WPF.GetInstance().TextBoxDebug, "test");` : "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form_WPF.GetInstance()"

Comment: Remove that line an try my sample code? Again, you should cast the `Child` property of the `ElementHost` control that hosts the WPF control.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of new with elementhosts and WPF. Where should I set this line (`Form_WPF wpfControl = elementHost.Host as Form_WPF; `)?

Comment: Wherever you want to access the WPF control in your WinForms app.

Comment: Ok so I have removed all the statics fields, and this is my btn_debug_click event:
`Form_WPF wpfControl = elementHost1.Child as Form_WPF;
   wpfControl.Dispatcher.Invoke(new ChangeTextBox_WPF(wpfControl._ChangeTextBox_WPF), wpfControl.TextBoxDebug, "test");`
But no change in the WPF textbox

Comment: Wait hold on, this is working! My element host was hosted both in my main winforms forms and another winforms forms, and I was checking the other winforms forms. But with inside the main winforms, this is changing. Thanks @mm8 !

Comment: So last question, how could I do if I have multiple elementhost and all of them have the same hosted WPF usercontrol and I want them to be the same ? Cast the child property to each elementhost to the WPF, and copy each time the code same lines ?

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. Avoid extended discussions in comments.